How to draw KML LineString with icons at each point
I'm trying to figure out how to draw a line in KML with some sort of indicators at each point in the line.
For an overly simplified example, say someone is hiking and they periodically record their position. The person walks from point A to B to C, but it just so happens that point B is on the direct line from A to C.
From a KML point of view, using LineString to draw a 2-point line from A -> C will look identical to drawing a 3-point line from A -> B -> C. So what I'd like to do is include all the recorded points in the LineString and put some sort of indicator on each recorded point so someone viewing the KML file can easily determine where actual recorded positions are vs. all the interpolated positions that are created by the lines connecting those points.
Unless I'm missing something, there's nothing in LineStyle that would cause Google Earth to draw an indicator at the actual points. So the only solution I'm seeing is to include all my points in the LineString and then include them all again as individual Point objects.
Am I missing some other option?

gpx would be better based on your current requirements.

Thanks for the response, but can you elaborate on that?
I realize I might not have been clear in the original post, but I need to display the data in Google Earth. That's a hard requirement at the moment.
